# Why is the whole list not wrapping around the wrapper?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to create a marquee text element, but one of the list items is leaking of out the list, I have no clue why that might be happening. Can someone help regarding this? I've attached a picture of what is happening and how can I make it one straight wrapper. https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIX85.png

```js
var $tickerWrapper = $(".tickerwrapper");
var $list = $tickerWrapper.find("ul.list");
var $clonedList = $list.clone();
var listWidth = 10;

$list.find("li").each(function (i) {
  listWidth += $(this, i).outerWidth(true);
});

var endPos = $tickerWrapper.width() - listWidth;

$list.add($clonedList).css({
  width: listWidth + "px",
});

$clonedList.addClass("cloned").appendTo($tickerWrapper);

//TimelineMax
var infinite = new TimelineMax({
  repeat: -1,
  paused: true,
});
var time = 40;

infinite
  .fromTo(
    $list,
    time,
    {
      rotation: 0.01,
      x: 0,
    },
    {
      force3D: true,
      x: -listWidth,
      ease: Linear.easeNone,
    },
    0
  )
  .fromTo(
    $clonedList,
    time,
    {
      rotation: 0.01,
      x: listWidth,
    },
    {
      force3D: true,
      x: 0,
      ease: Linear.easeNone,
    },
    0
  )
  .set($list, {
    force3D: true,
    rotation: 0.01,
    x: listWidth,
  })
  .to(
    $clonedList,
    time,
    {
      force3D: true,
      rotation: 0.01,
      x: -listWidth,
      ease: Linear.easeNone,
    },
    time
  )
  .to(
    $list,
    time,
    {
      force3D: true,
      rotation: 0.01,
      x: 0,
      ease: Linear.easeNone,
    },
    time
  )
  .progress(1)
  .progress(0)
  .play();

//Pause/Play
$tickerWrapper
  .on("mouseenter", function () {
    infinite.pause();
  })
  .on("mouseleave", function () {
    infinite.play();
  });
```

```css
.tickerwrapper {
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0%;
  background: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul.list {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  color: aliceblue;
}

ul.list.cloned {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

ul.list li {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.client_img {
  height: 4vw;
  padding-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.11.4/TweenMax.min.js"></script>


<div class="tickerwrapper">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="listitem">
      <img alt="3d logo" class="client_img" src="https://assets.stickpng.com/images/60e7f964711cf700048b6a6a.png" />
    </li>
    <li class="listitem">
      <img alt="3d logo" class="client_img" src="https://assets.stickpng.com/images/60e7f964711cf700048b6a6a.png" />
    </li>
    <li class="listitem">
      <img alt="3d logo" class="client_img" src="https://assets.stickpng.com/images/60e7f964711cf700048b6a6a.png" />
    </li>
    <li class="listitem">
      <img alt="3d logo" class="client_img" src="https://assets.stickpng.com/images/60e7f964711cf700048b6a6a.png" />
    </li>
    <li class="listitem">
      <img alt="3d logo" class="client_img" src="https://assets.stickpng.com/images/60e7f964711cf700048b6a6a.png" />
    </li>
    <li class="listitem">
      <img alt="3d logo" class="client_img" src="https://assets.stickpng.com/images/60e7f964711cf700048b6a6a.png" />
    </li>
    <li class="listitem">
      <img alt="3d logo" class="client_img" src="https://assets.stickpng.com/images/60e7f964711cf700048b6a6a.png" />
    </li>
    <li class="listitem">
      <img alt="3d logo" class="client_img" src="https://assets.stickpng.com/images/60e7f964711cf700048b6a6a.png" />
    </li>
    <li class="listitem">
      <img alt="3d logo" class="client_img" src="https://assets.stickpng.com/images/60e7f964711cf700048b6a6a.png" />
    </li>
    <li class="listitem">
      <img alt="3d logo" class="client_img" src="https://assets.stickpng.com/images/60e7f964711cf700048b6a6a.png" />
    </li>
    <li class="listitem">
      <img alt="3d logo" class="client_img" src="https://assets.stickpng.com/images/60e7f964711cf700048b6a6a.png" />
    </li>
    <li class="listitem">
      <img alt="3d logo" class="client_img" src="https://assets.stickpng.com/images/60e7f964711cf700048b6a6a.png" />
    </li>
    <li class="listitem">
      <img alt="3d logo" class="client_img" src="https://assets.stickpng.com/images/60e7f964711cf700048b6a6a.png" />
    </li>
    <li class="listitem">
      <img alt="3d logo" class="client_img" src="https://assets.stickpng.com/images/60e7f964711cf700048b6a6a.png" />
    </li>
    <li class="listitem">
      <img alt="3d logo" class="client_img" src="https://assets.stickpng.com/images/60e7f964711cf700048b6a6a.png" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I marked up your code as runnable snippet, but please further [edit] it so that it can actually run as [mcve].

Comment: Also some information about what "TimeLineMax" is would be useful.

Comment: Oh also also, why are you including jQuery 3 times?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I've made the edits, thank you for converting it!

Comment: @Pointy oh adding it 3 times was a mistake, I've corrected it. TimelineLineMax would potentially make it go forever, that was my initially assumption. Also, I've a the runnable snippet running now, but what issue I've is not showing here. No clue why.

Comment: @Isha your listitems are 15 and your list width is 10 ..